# Clicking on a link in a web page

Tags: powershell

I would really appreciate some help with a Powershell script.
On a Monday morning I log into a website with a username and password
I'm then presented with a screen with a list of files that can be downloaded
I click on the 2nd file in the list and it's downloaded to my laptop and I then
log out of the website. I now want to automate this using a powershell script.
So far my script successfully logs into the website but I can't get the script
to click on the file in the list to download it. I "right clicked" the filename and when
Inspect Element it produced the following

```
<tr>
<td class="filename">
<a href="/sfts/private/download.gmc?path=d%3a%5csfts%5cgroup%5cLRMP%5cgmclrmp.delta.20170909.zip">gmclrmp.delta.20170909.zip</a>
</td>
<td class="size">15964</td>
<td class="modified">09/09/2017 00:11</td>
</tr>
```

I've trawled through many websites looking for a solution but I seem to be missing something.
Can anyone help - I would be extremely grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try ? Usually, people will be more inclined to help if you can show what script you got at this point. You should include code snippets of what you did attempt when asking a question. Anyway, see my answer, it might just be what you seeked.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that would do the trick... 
This script open a IE object, navigate to the website and click on the second website.

```
$url = 'https://website.com' 

$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate($url)
$ie.visible = $true
while($ie.busy) {sleep 1}

$doc = $ie.document
$doc.links[1].click()

#Quit IE when you are done. 
#$ie.quit()
```

Comment: i've now cracked it - the solution is:

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked

$Filename="gmclrmp.delta."+$Today+".zip"
write-host "Filename = $Filename"
$links = $ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName('A') | where {$_.innerText -match "$Filename"}
$links.click()